# Unable to update profile details without changing current profile picture ,

Tags: laravel

I have successful in uploading profile picture  for first time entering the candidate profile details.When i try to update/edit their profile,the problem is when i edit details with updating profile picture it is successfully updating but when i try to change details of candidate without changing their old picture the data is not saving .I am using laravel .Please try to find solution for this problem..

---

```
public function profileupdate(Request $request)
    {
          $est =DB::table('candidate')->where('user_id','=',$request->input('id'))->get();
        $oldimage=$est[0]->image;
        $fileNameToStore=$oldimage;

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
           $this->validate($request,['image'=>'image|nullable|max:1999']);

           //get file name with extension
           $filenameWithExt=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
           //getjust file name
           $fileName=pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
           //get jsut ext
           $extension=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
           //file name to store
           $fileNameToStore=$fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
           // echo $fileNameToStore;die();
           //upload images 
           $path=$request->file('image')->storeAs('public/cand_images',$fileNameToStore);
           $newimage=$fileNameToStore;
       }

       Candidate::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
           ->update([
            'phone'=>$request->input('phone'),
            'email'=>$request->input('email'),
            'address'=>$request->input('address'),
            'city'=>$area[0]->area,
             'image'=>$fileNameToStore]);
           File::delete(public_path('storage/cand_images/'.$oldimage));
           return redirect('dashboard')->with('status','Profile Updated Successfully'); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the data from the update method to another array such as:

```
$data = ['phone'=>$request->input('phone'),
         'email'=>$request->input('email'),
         'address'=>$request->input('address'),
         'city'=>$area[0]->area];
```

This way you can add additional condition of when to update the image:

```
if (condition is true) {
   $data['image'] = $fileNameToStore;
}
```

And pass it to the update function:

```
Candidate::where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)
           ->update($data);
```

Comment: :) ,its successful. 
Thank u so much

Comment: No problem mate :)